# Replacing object from itself in C++

Tags: c++, oop, object, pointers

How can an object replace itself in ASNI C++ ? I want a function like foo->replaceBy(bar)
which will cause object foo to delete itself and replace pointer by bar

```
if (foo->isFoo())
{
    foo->replaceBy(bar);
}

ASSERT(foo->isFoo(), false);
ASSERT(foo->isBar(), true);
```

Comment: There's an assignment operator (which you can even overload if needed) for that purpose.

Comment: have you tried the = operator?

Comment: "Replace itself"? Explain what do you mean...

Comment: If you think about it - you got problems.

Comment: @m0skit0 it would be nicier to do { foo->replaceBy(bar); } instead of { delete foo; foo = bar; }, and i want to know how to implement it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this unless you pass a pointer to the pointer or a reference to the pointer ([example here](http://ideone.com/lwV9u)):

```
void replaceBy(Foo*& foo, Foo* bar) {
  delete foo;
  foo = bar;
}

//...

foo->replaceBy(foo, bar);
```

Which would defeat the purpose of `replaceBy` being a non-static member function.

---

There is also the überevil macro way to do this (**don't**):

```
#define FOO_REPLACE_BY(foo, bar) do {delete foo; foo = bar;} while(0)
```

---

I recommend that you overload `operator=` and stay away from pointers when possible, or at least use smart pointers (which allow for pointer assignment without memory leaks).

Comment: Well, foo isn't _necessarily_ a pointer, it could be an object with a -> overload containing a pointer. Exploring that option is still nothing to recommend though, and I'm not sure const-ness even makes it an option if you would :-)

Answer (score 1):

A pointer *cannot* replace itself – the object can of course modify itself but `this` is `const`, and since there may be more than one pointer pointing to an object there is logically no way how an object may know which pointer it belongs to (it simply doesn’t belong to a single or even any pointer).

However, maybe the [Envelope–Letter pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Envelope_Letter) is of help for your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the `PIMPL` idiom it's easy to *effectively* let objects take each others place: [The Pimpl Idiom in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843389/the-pimpl-idiom-in-practice)

Perhaps you also want a `swap` method to swap the contents of two objects.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/843418/1149664