# struct keyword in C++ typedef

Tags: c++, c

I was looking at Glew's header and I ran across something that raised a question for me:

```
// C
typedef struct __GLsync *GLsync;
```

I understand that Glew is a C library, therefore different from C++ and I know that this is a valid code in C++:

```
// C++
struct S { ... }; // S defined in the class name space
void f( S a ); // struct is optional
```

My question is, is it safe to remove the struct keyword from the `typedef` in C++ and include the header in a C++ only project?

```
typedef /*struct*/ __GLsync *GLsync;
```

If not, what would be the difference when I do a `typedef` with `struct` keyword and without it?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: The correct way to mix C and C++ code is with "extern".

Comment: To address your question more directly, though - in C++ 'struct' is very, very similar to 'class'.   But there are some differences.  If you want a plain old C struct, "extern".

Comment: @user93353 I do not want to remove it, I am just wondering because it looks cleaner without the `struct` keyword to me.

Comment: The former (with `struct`) will compile regardless of whether `__GLsync` is previously declared or not in the same translation unit, declaring a typedef of a pointer to some structure type (which may not be known at that point) called `_GLsync`. The latter (without `struct`) requires prior definition of the actual structure, or you will have an unknown type error.

Comment: @WhozCraig So with `struct` keyword, it also forward declares the structure as well?

Comment: @BadZen: You mean `extern "C"`, not just `extern`

Comment: I meant "using the keyword 'extern'", but yeah, that's how you use it.  (You forgot the {}!  :)  )

Comment: @3p3r yes, something like that. You can `typedef struct Something *SomeThingPtr;` without prior encounter of `Something` in the translation unit. The compiler will see it, and simply deduce "I don't know what this is, but I don't really need to know to declare a pointer alias to one." That is markedly different than `typedef Something *SomethingPtr;` which must have prior knowledge of what `Something` is. Of course by the time any code actually attempts to *dereference* a `SomethingPtr` the definition of `Something` has to have made its way into the translation unit. This is common in pimpls.

Comment: @WhozCraig Could you please make it an answer? that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @BadZen: What does `extern` have to do with it? The question is about `struct` type. It has absolutely nothing to do with linkage specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typedef of the following form:

```
typedef struct S *SPtr;
```

does not need prior knowledge of what `S` is in the same translation unit. It assumes a forward declaration of some structure `S` and aliases `SPtr` as a pointer type to said-same. However, this:

```
typedef S *SPtr; // error unless S is declared earlier
```

requires the declaration of the type `S` (which may be a structure) is already known prior to the declaration of the pointer alias type.

While this may seem trivial, it is a cornerstone of common implementations of the [pimpl idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843389/the-pimpl-idiom-in-practice). Note the `typedef` isn't really involved here, the announcement of `struct MyClassImpl*` as a pointer type to an unknown "thing" to-be-determined later (but prior to actual dereference) is what is important:

**MyClass.h**

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS
#define MY_CLASS

class MyClass
{
   ... members ...

private:
    struct MyClassImpl * m_pimpl; // note no MyClassImpl yet known
};

#endif
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"  

// implementation formal declaration and implementation.
struct MyClassImpl
{
    ... members...
};

// MyClass implementation using the now-known MyClassImpl
```

Had that pointer been declared as:

```
MyClassImpl * m_pimpl;
```

the type `MyClassImpl` would require prior declaration or a compile-time error would ensue.

I hope that helps identify a key difference between the two methods of declaration. (and yes, I know, I should have used a smart pointer =P)

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer here is **maybe**. It depends on what other code is found before it.

That being said, you can absolutely change this:

```
typedef struct __GLsync *GLsync;
```

To this:

```
struct __GLsync;
typedef __GLsync *GLsync;
```

Comment: Well this just looks cleaner to me. It clearly shows that something is being forward declared and then being used in a `typedef` and I actually ended up doing this in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `struct` keyword from `typedef` then you have to do things like this:

```
typedef struct S { ... }__GLsync; // S defined in the class name space
```

then you can use:

```
typedef  __GLsync  *GLsync;
```

Appended Question:

If `struct` is already definded by already some else then how to do work around then

```
 typedef struct __GLsync  *abc;
 typdef  *abc       GLsync
```

You can do things like this

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but this involves defining the `struct` myself, which sometimes is impossible since the `struct` is defined somewhere else and all I want to do is a simple `typedef`