# Can I provide an incomplete header for a C++ class to hide the implementation details?

Tags: c++, include, api-design

I would like to split a class implementation into three parts, to avoid that users need to deal with the implementation details, e.g., the libaries that I use to implement the functionality:

impl.cpp

```
#include <api.h>
#include <impl.h>
Class::Class() {
    init();
}
Class::init() {
    myData = SomeLibrary::Type(42);
}
Class::doSomething() {
    myData.doSomething();
}
```

impl.h

```
#include <somelibrary.h>
class Class {
public:
    Class();
    init();
    doSomething();
private:
    SomeLibary::Type myData;
}
```

api.h

```
class Class {
    Class();
    doSomething();
}
```

The problem is, that I am not allowed to redefine headers for the class definition. This does not work when I define `Class()` and `doSomething()` only in `api.h`, either.

---

A possible option is to define `api.h` and do not use it in the project at all, but install it (and do not install `impl.h`).

The obvious drawback is, that I need to make sure, that the common methods in `api.h` and `impl.h` always have the same signature, otherwise programs using the library will get linker errors, that I cannot predict when compiling the library.

But would this approach work at all, or will I get other problems (e.g. wrong pointers to class members or similar issues), because the obj file does not match the header?

Comment: You may be looking for the [PIMPL idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) (and here's a SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843389/the-pimpl-idiom-in-practice).

Comment: Future *Module* of c++20 might help to limit exposition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is "No!"

The reason: any/all 'client' projects that need to use your `Class` class have to have the ***full declaration*** of that class, in order that the compiler can properly determine such things as offsets for member variables.

The use of `private` members is fine - client programs won't be able to change them - as is your current implementation, where only the briefest outlines of member functions are provided in the header, with all actual definitions in your (private) source file.

A possible way around this is to declare a ***pointer*** to a nested class in `Class`, where this nested class is simply declared in the shared header: `class NestedClass` and then you can do what you like with that nested class pointer in your implementation. You would generally make the nested class pointer a `private` member; also, as its definition is not given in the shared header, any attempt by a 'client' project to access that class (other than as a pointer) will be a compiler error.

Here's a possible code breakdown (maybe not error-free, yet, as it's a quick type-up):

```
// impl.h
struct MyInternal; // An 'opaque' structure - the definition is For Your Eyes Only
class Class {
public:
    Class();
    init();
    doSomething();
private:
    MyInternal* hidden; // CLient never needs to access this! Compiler error if attempted.
}

// impl.cpp
#include <api.h>
#include <impl.h>

struct MyInternal {
    SomeLibrary::Type myData;
};

Class::Class() {
    init();
}
Class::init() {
    hidden = new MyInternal; // MUCH BETTER TO USE unique_ptr, or some other STL.
    hidden->myData = SomeLibrary::Type(42);
}
Class::doSomething() {
    hidden->myData.doSomething();
}
```

NOTE: As I hinted in a code comment, it would be better code to use `std::unique_ptr<MyInternal> hidden`. However, this would require you to give **explicit** definitions in your `Class` for the destructor, assignment operator and others (move operator? copy constructor?), as these will need access to the full definition of the `MyInternal` struct.

Comment: My problem is, that I want to avoid recursive includes to ``SomeLibrary``, just because some private members use types from the library. The library is header only, so there is no need for programs to know, that my library is using it. I currently try to use two separate headers, with an ``api.h`` header that is not included at all in my implementation. Does this cause problems because of the offset calculation you mentioned?

Comment: I edited my question. An option without pimpl seems to be, that I duplicate ``impl.h`` and remove everything that's private. Then I only link with ``impl.h`` in the library and only install ``api.h``. Would this work?

Comment: @allo You could (in fact, you ***should***) use the `impl.h` header for both the exported (client-mode) projects and in your own implementation files. Putting the 'same' class definition in two different headers is really asking for trouble, further down the road.

Comment: The ``impl.h`` header contains the dependencies, that I do not want to expose. Reusing the ``api.h`` header does not work because of the redefinition of the class. So I would probably either need to try using the headers only seperate or I should use the pImpl solution.

Answer (score 2):

The private implementation (PIMPL) idiom can help you out here. It will probably result in 2 header and 2 source files instead of 2 and 1. Have a silly example I haven't actually tried to compile:

api.h

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
struct foo_impl;
struct foo {
    int do_something(int argument);
private:
    std::unique_ptr<foo_impl> impl;
}
```

api.c

```
#include "api.h"
#include "impl.h"
int foo::do_something(int a) { return impl->do_something(); }
```

impl.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
struct foo_impl {
    foo_impl();
    ~foo_impl();
    int do_something(int);
    int initialize_b();
private:  
    int b;
};
```

impl.c

```
#include <iostream>
foo_impl::foo_impl() : b(initialize_b()} {  }
foo_impl::~foo_impl() = default;
int foo_impl::do_something(int a) { return a+b++; }
int foo_impl::initialize_b() { ... }
```

`foo_impl` can have whatever methods it needs, as `foo`'s header (the API) is all the user will see. All the compiler needs to compile `foo` is the knowledge that there is a pointer as a data member so it can size `foo` correctly.

Comment: This looks good, but when my program tries to link against the library I get an error for ``foo_impl``, that the ``unique_ptr`` cannot delete an incomplete type, with the assert in memory: ``static_assert(0 < sizeof (_Ty)``.

Comment: I needed to declare a destructor for ``foo`` and add ``~foo() = default;`` to ``impl.c``, so the foo class destroys the unique pointer in its (hidden) implementation.

Comment: @allo Thanks. I'll add it. As I said, I hadn't tried to compile it. I'm glad it worked mostly though.