# Can I define a class member variable in C++ be multiple data types?

Tags: c++, class, operating-system

So I have a class definition, and I want to add a member variable that can be 1 of 2 different classes depending on the operating system this code is run on.

Is there anyway to do this in C++ so that I can initialize a different class for the "operating_system" member variable depending on some arguement or variable when initializing MyOperatingSystem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Win.h"
#include "Lin.h"

using namespace std;

typedef int os_type;
enum {Win, Lin};

class MyOperatingSystem {
  public:
    MyOperatingSystem(int ver, string n, os_type os);
  private:           
    int version;
    string name;
    // operating_system // want this to be either (Windows win | Linux lin)

};

// constructor
MyOperatingSystem::MyOperatingSystem(int ver, string n, os_type os){
    version = ver;
    name = n;
    if (os == Win){
        // operating system = Windows(int i);
    }
    else{
        // operating system = Linux(int i)
    }
}
```

Win.h and Lin.h are as follows

Win.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
class Windows{
    public:
        Windows(int i){
            integer = i;
            mystring = "WinString";
        }
    private:
        int integer;
        LPCWSTR mystring;
};
```

Lin.h:

```
#include <termios.h>
class Linux{
    public:
        Linux(int i){
            integer = i;
            mystring = "LinString";
        }
    private:
        int integer;
        cc_t* mystring;
};
```

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843389/the-pimpl-idiom-in-practice

Comment: For your specific use case, you might profit from the already existing implementations like e.g. ncurses.

Comment: Do you want to use the Windows implementation only on Windows platforms and the Linux implementation only on Linux, or both implementations on both platforms?

Comment: Create an abstract baseclass with pure virtual functions (interface, non-copyable, non-moveable), provide 2 different implementations and depending on the platform instantiate one or the other, use the interface in all other places of the code (compile time ifdef). As a bonus, the interface will also allow you to create mocks and stubs for unit testing.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest making a compile-time decision.

Example:

```
#pragma once // MyOperatingSystem.h

class IOperatingSystem {
public:
    virtual ~IOperatingSystem() = default;

    // misc operations:
    virtual foo() = 0;
};

#ifdef _WIN32
#include "internal/Win.h" // in here MyOperatingSystem  implements  IOperatingSystem 
#else
#include "internal/Lin.h" // in here MyOperatingSystem  implements  IOperatingSystem 
#endif
```

You don't necessarily need `virtual` here but it helps when designing to make sure that both implementations follow the same interface.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily need to be virtual.

Comment: Why make this virtual?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I'd design this class mainly by adding pure virtual methods to the interface. A compilation with either Windows or Linux as a target would show if I've overridden all these methods and that the signatures matches. It's convenient. One can also easily make "flavors". It could be `internal/unixlike.h` and in there you could have layers of inheritance, all chosen at compile-time. One of the "unix-like" OSes may need to `override` a default implementation of a method. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious solution is to have a base `OperatingSystem` class with a common interface, and derive your `Win` and `Linux` from it.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system is a compile time thing so you can use a template parameter

```
template <ostype os> class MyOperatingSystem ...
```

You can then use `if constexpr` to check which os you have and include different code in the class. The `Windows` and `Linux` classes should probably have a common base class and then most of the differences would be solved by virtual methods. So `if constexpr (os == Win) ...` should be the exception.

Another way to go would be a dependency insertion:

```
MyOperatingSystem(int ver, string n, Os & os);
```

where `Os` is the common base class for `Windows` and `Linux`.

Or again, since this is a compile time thing:

```
template <typename Os> class MyOperatingSystem : public Os { ... }
template <typename Os> class MyOperatingSystem  { ... Os os; }
```

In this case you don't even need a common base class (but it helps to ensure a common interface). Both `Windows` and `Linux` just have to follow a common interface, like defining an `os_type`. If `Os::os_type` is a constexpr you could use `if constexpr` again. But I think the point of the Os classes is to encapsulate all the OS specific code so again that should be rare if used at all.

Note that with the `Os` template way the `MyOperatingSystem` class is (or has) a concrete `Windows` or `Linux` class. So all the virtual function calls get replaced by concrete calls. So no overhead. The earlier cases have a pointer or reference to the base class and will need to do virtual method calls.

Answer (score -3):

```
std::variant<Windows, Linux> operating_system;
```

`std::variant` is a sum type -- it is one of the types in the list of types.

As a side effect, it carries with it the type it is -- so the `os_type` variable is redundant to store beside it.

Comment: This isn't really the best solution.

Comment: This is something that should be done statically...